# Connection refused while connect with RabbitMQ external service

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, rabbitmq

I am trying to connect with RabbitMQ external server, but get following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.createFrameHandler(ConnectionFactory.java:362)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:400)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:423)
    at com.towertech.JSONSend.run(JSONSend.java:36)
    at com.towertech.JSONSend.main(JSONSend.java:63)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.towertech.JSONSend.run(JSONSend.java:54)
    at com.towertech.JSONSend.main(JSONSend.java:63)
```

My code looks the following:

```
public class JSONSend {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "json-example";
    private ConnectionFactory factory = null;
     
    public JSONSend() 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
     
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        factory = new ConnectionFactory(); 
        Connection connection = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        try{ 
        
             factory.setHost("172.26.10.805");
             factory.setPort(5672);
             factory.setUsername("TEST");
             factory.setPassword("TEST@123");
             factory.setVirtualHost("TEST");

            connection = factory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();
            channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("message", String.format("Person", i));
                obj.put("mask", String.format("TTL", i));
                obj.put("destination_address", String.format("03215929139", i));
             
                channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, obj.toJSONString().getBytes()); 
                System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + obj.toJSONString() + "'");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            if(channel!=null){
                channel.close();
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }
     
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
     {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      JSONSend test = new JSONSend();
      test.run();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My port was block, after port open my connection is now established but msg don't sent